# Hosting the WCF Service in windows service

Tags: wcf, service

How to host the WCF service in windows service?

Thanks
Sekar

Answer (score 7):

I thought this article did a pretty good job of covering the steps required:
[WCF Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

To summarize:

- To start with you need to create a new visual studio project of the type "Windows Service".
- Next to be able to install the service, you also need to write an installer class of the form:

.

```
 [RunInstaller(true)]
 public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
 {
 }
```

- Add your WCF classes to the project, and in the OnStart and OnStop events of the windows service you'll have to explicitly start your WCF services.
- From a visual studio command prompt you can install the service using the command

.

```
installutil myservicename.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this today come across Channel 9:

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Hosting-WCF-Services-in-Windows-Services/